# While loop help in Shell Script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am new to shell scripting so I am curious about using While Loops in Shell Script form.

I know how to declare a variable and use a while loop in java

```
int num = 0;
while(num <= 10)
{
    System.out.println(num)
    num = num + 1
}
```

But I don't know how to declare variables and use them in a while loop in a Shell Script.

Comment: Mm... why a debian tag?

Comment: @Braiam The tag could be removed, this is a general programming question (it could also be posted on SO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be much happier using a `for` loop instead (according to your example)

```
for i in {0..10}; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

If you *must* use a `while` loop, consider the following

```
i=0
while [[ $i -le 10 ]]; do
    echo "$i"
    i=$((i+=1))
done
```

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways of doing this, but the shell script which most closely mirrors your Java example is this:

```
num=0
while test $num -le 10; do
    echo $num
    num=$((num+1))
done
```

A more 'shell-ish' ways to achieve the same would be

```
printf '%s\n' {0..9}
```

But note that the `{0..9}` construction is a 'bashism', which will not work in the standard (POSIX) shell.

Comment: I used this example and I got an error. "line 4: num: command not found.

Comment: Oh I should add, when i execute the fileName.sh file i use bash fileName.sh.  My first line of the file is #!/bin/sh.  I'm not sure if any of that makes a difference

Comment: @user1984712 You got "command not found" because you added a space between `num` and the `=` sign.

Comment: No, in bash we would do this: `printf '%s\n' {0..9}`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That actually looks better than the echo, I'll add it.

Comment: @zwets I checked and I did not have a space between the num and = sign

Comment: @user1984712 You can't execute the file as `bash file.sh` and have a `#!/bin/sh` line at the top. You should change the `#!` line to be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @minerz029 It gives the error either way

Comment: Line 4 should be `num=$(($num+1))` to fix the bug

Comment: @Germar No, line 4 is fine. The `num` is inside an arithmetic expression. Have you actually tried?

Comment: @user1984712 The code should work in both `bash` and (POSIX) `sh`, regardless of whether it is in a file, with or without shebang header. Please **copy and paste** the code into a shell and report if the error still exists. If so, what is the output of `$0 --version` in your shell?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another simple way:

```
num=0
while (($num <= 10)); do
    echo "$num"
    ((num++))
done
```

This will work in bash, but not in a standard POSIX shell.

Answer (score -2):

This Bash Scripting site should help you, generally you don't have to declare variables before you use them:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: Oh dear, please don't link to such horrible documents! This document really shows **what you should not do** rather than showing good practices!

Comment: Whats wrong with it? I was just going to say that it worked

Comment: @user1984712 What's wrong? Parsing output of `ls`, lacks of quotes, outdated C-loop style, use of capitalized variable names, use of `let` instead of bash's arithmetic, use of `[]` instead of `[[...]]` or of bash's arithmetic, ... please, just don't read this document, unless you want to write crappy code and not learn proper bash.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf if it's that bad, you should downvote it.

Comment: Hm, that wasn't updated since 2000. Is http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ better?